# I want to extract all the variable names with a python script, from a python file, without editing the python file

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am making a text editor in which I can make a variable explorer. So what I want to do is by using my python script which is text editor I want to get all the variable names from the code that my text editor is editing.

if not clear so again > I had made a text editor and if a user is editing any python file by using my editor so there is a function which will extract all the variables from the file which the user is editing.

If possible get all the values of variables

Thanks in advance.

I tried using vars() but it does not apply for strings because I can only get the text in string format using 
    txt.get('1.0','end')
but i it s not write.
I also tried to embed vars() in the editing file(the file edited by the user)
but I am not getting any good result or you can say no result.

and I don't know how to use "*dir*" or how can I use it in this script to get variables names.

So my expected result is when the user presses a button a function start and get all the variables and their values from the python file that the user is editing currently.
like an example script

```
class example():
    def example_define():
        a=1
        b=2
        c=3
```

and the function return like

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir and __dict__` can be useful to know all the attributes inside of an object based on the type. For Example, 
Let's consider this code `code.py`.

```
class example():
    def example_define(self):
        a=1
        b=2
        c=3
d = 1

def hello():
    print("world")
```

On the other file `debug.py` you can try this.

```
import code
print(code.__dict__) # prints a dictionary of all the attributes and their values.
print(dir(code)) # prints a list of all the attributes.
```

Also if you have an object `o` you can call `dir(o)` to know the attributes of the object. If it supports, you can try `o.__dict__`.

---

**Scope wise availability**

```
class Example():
    def example_define(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

o = Example()
print(dir(o)) # Doesn't give a, b, c
o.example_define()
print(dir(o)) # Gives a, b, c
```

Comment: I am only getting the variables of the functions in the file. Is there any way to get all the variables including integers, strings, list, dictionary, functions, used in that script.

Comment: I think the availability is based on scope and declaration. In the above example class if we can change the variables to `self.a=1` etc. We can get those by simply creating an object of the class and calling `example_define` on it and `dir` of the object.

Comment: Can you give an example of it because I am not able to understand?