# How to extract all variable and their value from a python script with location like "C:\\Users\\SomeFolder\\PythonFile.py"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am working on a text editor made with python and i want to add a feature of Variable Explorer in my editor I am not able to extract the variable values from a python file. My basic working principle is that my program takes location of the current edited file and try to import it but I am not able to import because that is string not an object. It is bit confusing so let me show the code.

```
fileName='C:\Users\Project.py'
class varExplorer:
    def ShowVarList(editfile):
       editfile.replace('\','.')
       editfile.replace('.py','')
       editfile.replace(':','')
       # so the file path will be like C.Users.Project
       import editfile # the problem
       print(editfile.__dict__)# here i will get dictionary of values

varExplorer.ShowVarList(fileName)
```

help taken for **dict**

```
print(editfile.__dict__)
```

from
[I want to extract all the variable names with a python script, from a python file, without editing the python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473621/i-want-to-extract-all-the-variable-names-with-a-python-script-from-a-python-fil)

#### The main problem is that it cannot import from a string

```
import editfile # the problem
```

#### because it is a string and import does not take strings

So I want a function which can print all the variable and their values from a specific python file from any location.

Comment: Your editor shouldn't import the file being edited. I recommend `ast`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html or similar approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `importlib`

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(editfile)
```

Also be careful, `str` is immutable in Python, `replace` returns a new string and does not modify its argument.
So you get:

```
import importlib

class VarExplorer:
    def show_var_list(editfile):
       editfile = editfile.replace('\\','.')
       editfile = editfile.replace('.py','')
       editfile = editfile.replace(':','')
       # so the file path will be like C.Users.Project
       module = importlib.import_module(editfile) # the solution
       print(vars(module))
```

Comment: What will this do please edit it and add an explanation.

Comment: Ok so how will i be able to use .__dict__ to extract variable

Comment: `object.__dict__` and `vars(object)` are equivalent, the latter being more pythonic as it avoid to use a special hidden variable.

Comment: it is showing error                                                                                                        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'D:\\Sync\\HelpUtilities\\compileman'

Comment: So `editfile` in `importlib.import_module(editfile)` is 'D:\\Sync\\HelpUtilities\\compileman', which is obviously not a package name. Did you correct your code with `editfile = editfile.replace...` ? It seems the replacements have not been done.

Comment: Plus your package must be found by Python, so must start from a path in `sys.path`.

Comment: Please upvote question of it was helpful to community.